# Pull certain data from log file

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

I'm creating a program that will sort IP addresses based on how many times users visit a site per day. I will get my data from an apache log file.[This is the example I'll learn from](http://www.almhuette-raith.at/apache-log/access.log)

Is there any library or inbuilt function that I can use in order to only append the ip addresses and dates from the log?

I've searched online for information about this, however, if there's any documentation that seem usefull I would be very intrested in reading it!

I've tried with creating a list, where I append each line to. My question is that I'm looking for a better way to do this and instead of appending the whole line, to only append the ip address and the date.

Comment: Did you try just keeping track of which IP addresses have visited how many times? A dictionary might help.

Comment: @viktor, pm me if you nee more help.

Comment: @AJ_ Okay thanks! ^^ Would you mind comment further in the file? Is storage_file where I have my log, or is it the one I'm writing too?

A small comment on which file is for what would be helpful! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(log_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        IP, date = line.partition("]")[0].split(" - - [")
```

Given the example log file, if each new line starts with an IP, then that should be enough. How you store it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the ip is listed first. That means you can read a file, line by line, and strip out the first word, being the ip, and append it to a list to be returned. If you wish to do more advance searching/filtering, i would suggest formatting that log, by reading and writing that log file, to a xml or json type format. It will be easier to search than blocks of strings.

```
 def append_log_storage(file, storage_file):
    root_elm = ET.Element('root')  
    # Load file to memory
    log_content = None
    with open(file) as f:
        log_content = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    # Write to file    
    f = open(file, 'w')
    for line in log_content:
        if line == '\n':
            continue 
        ip = line.partition(' ')[0]
        ip_log_elm = ET.SubElement(root_elm, 'log')
        ip_elm = ET.SubElement(ip_log_elm, 'ip')  
        # date_elm, etc. Add any other data for the log element
        ip_elm.text = ip  
    f.close()
    xml_data = ET.tostring(root_elm)
    xml_file = open(storage_file, 'wb')
    xml_file.write(xml_data)

def read_log_details(file):
    # Read file by line
    ip_list = []
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line == '\n':
                continue 
            ip = line.partition(' ')[0]
            ip_list.append(ip)
    f.close()
    return ip_list

read_log_details('log.txt')
#append_log_storage('log.txt', 'log.xml')
```

https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-xml-files-in-python/